# JTextArea not wrapping when parent shrinks

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I am creating a Java Swing application that displays a chat log of messages. The frame holds only a `JScrollPane` which has a `VerticalLayout`, and in it are an indefinite number of `JTextArea`s, one for each message. The `JTextArea`s are uneditable, and the only reason I'm using them instead of a `JLabel` is because I need to wrap the text.

As a test, I create my frame and add two messages.

[image: JTextArea]

This is working as intended, the components form a continuous page of text and wrap around the frame.

I then increase the size of the frame.

[image: JTextArea expanded]

This is still working as intended, the `JScrollPane` and `JTextArea`s have expanded and the text has rewrapped itself.

I then shrink the window back to a smaller size.

[image: JTextArea shrunk]

This is not working as intended. The `JScrollPane` stays at its largest size and the words do not wrap. How can I make it so that when the frame is shrunk width-wise, the `JScrollPane` and `JTextArea`s are shrunk as well?

Things I have already tried:

- Instantiating the `JScrollPane` with `JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER`
- Giving each `JTextArea` a `BoxLayout` or `BorderLayout`
- Wrapping each `JTextArea` in a `JPanel` and giving the panel a `BoxLayout` or `BorderLayout`
- Revalidating/redrawing the `JScrollPane` upon resizing events
- Calling `setSize(Dimension d)` of `JScrollPane` with `getSize()` of `JFrame` upon resizing events

EDIT: A minimum verifiable example, that produces the same effect as the described above

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import org.jfree.ui.tabbedui.VerticalLayout;

public class MessagingFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel textPanel;

    public MessagingFrame() {
        // Create display area
        textPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel.setLayout(new VerticalLayout());
        // Wrap text panel in scroll pane
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPanel);
        // Add scroll pane
        add(scrollPane);
        // Size center and display
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addMessage(String message) {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(message);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textPanel.add(textArea);
        textPanel.updateUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MessagingFrame frame = new MessagingFrame();
        frame.addMessage("According to all known laws of aviation, there is no way a bee should be able to fly. Its wings are too small to get its fat little body off the ground. The bee, of course, flies anyway because bees don’t care what humans think is impossible.");
        frame.addMessage("We begin on Christmas Eve with me, Mark, and my roommate, Roger. We live in an industrial loft on the corner of 11th street and Avenue B, the top floor of what was once a music publishing factory. Old rock 'n' roll posters hang on the walls. They have Roger's picture advertising gigs at CBGB's and the Pyramid Club. We have an illegal wood burning stove; its exhaust pipe crawls up to a skylight. All of our electrical appliances are plugged into one thick extension cord which snakes its way out a window. Outside, a small tent city has sprung up in the lot next to our building. Inside, we are freezing because we have no heat.");
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't mess with `setSize`, the components are under the management of the layout manager.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I ran a quick test using a `VertialLayout` (from SwingLabs, SwingX library) and put a `JScrollPane` onto which wrapped a `JTextArea` (using word and line wrapping) and had no issues

Comment: @user3437460 My explanations are accompanied by screenshots, are they not loading for you?

Comment: @Phoenix You mentioned the words do not wrap in the last screen shot, but there is a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @user3437460 I do not want there to be a horizontal scrollbar, I need the `JScrollPane` to shrink horizontally such that there is no need for a horizontal scrollbar and the words wrap around the screen

Comment: @Phoenix So you want a vertical scrollbar if text gets longer by not a horizontal scroll bar. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the `Scrollable` interface on the panel you add to the scroll panel so that the `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()` method returns `true`.

This will force the component in the viewport to always be the same size as the viewport, not the width of the components added to the viewport.

When you implement the interface you will need to implement all the methods of the interface.

Or a simple solution is to use the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/) which implements the interface for you and you just set the properties you want.

So the basic code would be:

```
ScrollablePanel panel = new ScrollablePanel( new VerticalLayout());
panel.setScrollableWidth( ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.FIT );
panel.add(...);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( panel );
```

> Wrapping each JTextArea in a JPanel and giving the panel a BoxLayout or BorderLayout

You should be able to just add the text area directly to the panel. It appears the VerticalLayout makes each component as wide as possible.

> textPanel.updateUI();

Don't use updateUI() that is for a LAF change. When you add/remove components from a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add();
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Comment: @Phoenix Can you say which method worked for you? Could you imply the Scrollable Interface successfully? If so please can you share because I am not being able to do so.

Comment: @MohammadZulfikar I'm afraid I don't remember the details, this was so long ago. But if you've tried to implement it, but gotten stuck and have a specific question, that could make a good post of your own :)

Comment: @Phoenix It is alright! I will give some few more try and if I feel then I will post a new question. But thank you anyways :)